# Extract a specific layer from EXR

Tags: python, opencv, openexr

I have an EXR file, and I would like to extract and save on my machine, as a .png image, a specific layer given its name. I am currently using python, opencv and openexr. Not sure how to achieve this, any suggestion?
Thanks!

---

I was able to have openimageio run and work and so I was able to extract easily the layer I needed

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is your issue? Installation? Colour normalisation, quality loss? Please share some code, a sample EXR image that you are using and the expected result.

Comment: Hi Markus, given a EXR image that has different layers I would like to get a list of all of them and then specify which one(s) I would like to export and save as a png. Right now, I was just able to load the image and save it in a variable, but apart for that I have no clue on how to proceed. The only image I am working with, as a test, has only 1 layer (is a free HDRI I got from a website) but I know that there can be more than just 1 layer in some EXR.

Comment: How about sharing your code as an answer so other folks  can learn too?